# "Argument list too long" for every command

Tags: bash, list, arguments

Occasionally, when I have a program that generates large arrays I get this bug where every command throws the error 
"Argument list too long"
even if I just type:

```
$ cp
-bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long
$
```

I can't use `ls`, or even open a new file with `vim`:

```
$ vim test.txt
-bash: /usr/bin/vim: Argument list too long
$
```

I tried using "wait" for all bg processes to finish, but no change.  It seems to happen inconsistently, but when it does, the only fix is to restart the shell.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Update:  I did some further testing and i got the error to be repeatable.  It happens when a recursively defined array reaches 85 elements in length.  The first command which throws the error is a `bc` that doesnt even depend on the array! and then from there on out, almost every other command throws the same error.

Update:  The program I'm using has many bash scripts working together, but I've determined the problem always arises in this one:

```
function MPMDrun_prop()
{
PARDIR=$1
COMPDIR=$2
runSTR=$3
NUMNODES=$4
ForceRun=$5

if [ $# -le 3 ] ; then
echo "USAGE: MPMDrun_prop \$PARDIR \$COMPDIR \$runSTR \$NUMNODES \$ForceRun"
fi
echo "in MPMDrun_Prop"
. $PARDIR/ParameterScan.inp
. $MCTDHBDIR/Scripts/get_NumberOfJobs.sh

if [ "$MPMD" != "T" ]; then
  MPMDnodes=1
fi

## If no runscripts in the $PARDIR, copy one and strip of the line which runs the program
if [ -z "$(ls $PARDIR/run*.sh 2> /dev/null)"  ] ; then

 if [ "$forhost" == "maia" ]; then
   cp $MCTDHBDIR/../PBS_Scripts/run-example-maia.sh $PARDIR/run.tmp
   sed 's|mpirun.*||' < $PARDIR/run.tmp > $PARDIR/run.sh
   jobtime=86400
 elif [ "$forhost" == "hermit" ]; then
   cp $MCTDHBDIR/../PBS_Scripts/run-example-hermit.sh $PARDIR/run.tmp
   sed 's|aprun.*||' < $PARDIR/run.tmp > $PARDIR/run.sh
   jobtime=86400
 elif [ "$forhost" == "hornet" ]; then
   cp $MCTDHBDIR/../PBS_Scripts/run-example-hornet.sh $PARDIR/run.tmp
   sed 's|aprun.*||' < $PARDIR/run.tmp > $PARDIR/run.sh
   jobtime=86400
 elif [ "$forhost" == "bwgrid" ]; then
   cp $MCTDHBDIR/../PBS_Scripts/run-example-BWGRID.sh $PARDIR/run.tmp
   sed 's|mpirun.*||' < $PARDIR/run.tmp > $PARDIR/run.sh
   jobtime=86400
 fi
 sed 's|nodes=[0-9]*|nodes=0|' < $PARDIR/run.sh > $PARDIR/run.tmp
 sed 's|#PBS -N.*|#PBS -N MONSTER_'$MonsterName'|' < $PARDIR/run.tmp > $PARDIR/run.sh_

 rm $PARDIR/run.sh
 rm $PARDIR/run.tmp
 chmod 755 $PARDIR/run.sh_
 echo ". $MCTDHBDIR/Scripts/RunFlagSleeper.sh" >> $PARDIR/run.sh_
 ## Include check_convergence.sh for mixed relax/prop compatibility
 echo ". $MCTDHBDIR/Scripts/check_convergence.sh" >> $PARDIR/run.sh_
 echo "RunFlagSleeper $jobtime " >> $PARDIR/run.sh_
 echo "(" >> $PARDIR/run.sh_
 cp $PARDIR/run.sh_ $PARDIR/run1.sh
fi
### Add $runSTR to the most recent runscript
### find runscript$N.sh (run1.sh, run 2.sh, etc)  that has numnodes less than $MPMDnodes
for qq in $(ls $PARDIR/run[0-9]*.sh | sort -g ); do
  NodesInRun=$(cat $qq | grep -o "nodes *= *[0-9]*" | grep -o "[0-9]*")
  if [ "$NodesInRun" -lt "$MPMDnodes"  ]; then
   ## The number of nodes already specified in the runscript doesnt exceed the maximum, so add on another job
   NewNodes=$(echo "$NodesInRun+$NUMNODES" | bc)
   ## Start each aprun command in its own subshell
   ## wait for 24 hrs after aprun, to guarantee that no subshell finishes before the job is done
   sed 's|nodes=[0-9]*|nodes='$NewNodes'|' < $qq > $qq-1
   sed 's|\(RunFlagSleeper .*\)|\1 '$COMPDIR'|' <$qq-1 >$qq
   rm $qq-1
     echo "  (" >> $qq
     ## Sleeps for $jobtime - 5 mins, then removes runflag. in case aprun doesnt finish in $jobtime 
     echo "    cd $COMPDIR" >> $qq
     echo "    $runSTR" >> $qq
     ## remove runflag after aprun command has finished
     echo "    rm $COMPDIR/RunFlag" >> $qq
#     echo "sleep $jobtime" >> $qq-1
     echo "  ) &" >> $qq
#   mv $qq-1 $qq
   ## put a flag in the computation directory so it isnt computed multiple times
   touch $COMPDIR/RunFlag

   if [[ "$NewNodes" -ge "$MPMDnodes" || "$ForceRun" == "T"  ]]; then
    ## This last process made the nodecount exceed the maximum, or there is a ForceRun flag passed
    ## So now, exceute the runscript and start another
    echo "  wait" >> $qq
    echo ") &" >> $qq
    echo "PID=\$!" >> $qq
    echo "wait \$PID" >> $qq
    ## Ensure the queue has room for the next job, if not, wait for it
   Njobs=$(get_NumberOfJobs $runhost)
   while [ "$Njobs" -ge "$maxjobs" ]; do
    echo "Njobs=$Njobs and maxjobs=$maxjobs"
    echo "Waiting 30 minutes for que to clear"
    sleep 1800
   done
    echo "qsub $qq"
#    qsub $qq
    RunCount=$(echo $qq | grep -o 'run[0-9]*.sh' | grep -o '[0-9]*')
    let "RunCount++"
    cp $PARDIR/run.sh_ $PARDIR/run$RunCount.sh
   fi
  fi
done
}
```

The error typically starts at the 80-90'th call of this function at the first `cp` or `bc`.  I've commented ALL array manipulations, so there is zero chance this is caused by the array being too large.  The environment stays at ~100-200 Kb so that isn't the problem either.

Comment: Don't background it. Just leave it in the foreground and start a _new_ shell to do your other stuff. It's not like you will have a resource quota on windows :-)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear,
The main function is not in the bg.  I only use the bg for some parallel copying in this application.  
I just tried using "wait" because I didn't know what else to do.

Comment: Check whether you've set `ulimit -s 0` or equivalent (use `ulimit -s` to find the maximum size of the stack of a process in KiB).  If the stack size is too small (and/or your environment is too big), you will be unable to create any processes.  Of course, since you can't run `cp`, you won't be able to run `ulimit -s` either, which leaves us in a Catch-22 situation.  Can you run another terminal window and analyze `/dev/proc/NNNN` where `NNNN` is the PID of the shell that can't run anything?  (You might be able to unset some environment variables, too, if you know of any big ones.)

Comment: I checked `ulimit -s` and the result is `unlimited`, so it seems thats not the issue.

Answer (score 18):

That error message is a bit misleading. It should say something like "Argument list and environment use too much space".

The environment consists of all the environment variables you have exported, plus the environment your shell was started with. Normally, the environment should only be a few kilobytes, but there is nothing stopping you from `export`ing a million-byte string, and if you do that, you'll use up all the space allowed.

It's not totally obvious how much space the system allows for arguments + environment. You should be able to query the limit with `getconf ARG_MAX`, and with Gnu `xargs` you can get more information from `xargs --show-limits </dev/null` (in both cases, assuming you haven't exceeded the limit :) ), but sometimes the actual space available will turn out to be less than what is indicated.

In any event, it's not a good idea to try to stuff megabytes into the environment. If you're tempted to do that, put the data in a temporary file instead, and just export the name of the file.

Comment: My arrays are surely not megabytes.  They could only be a couple hundred elements, max.  And I encounter this error consistently when the array size reaches 85! I checked the maximum environment load and its several orders of magnitude bigger than I expect I'm using.  Unfortunately when the error kicks in, I cannot run xargs or getconf to confirm that.

Comment: Arrays cannot be exported so the problem is probably elsewhere. I should havee mentioned that. You can compute the total size of exported variables in pure bash... I'll add the incantation to the answer.

Comment: I inserted `echo "test" | xargs --show-limits` into my function so I can track the environment size as it runs.   

`Your environment variables take up 147121 bytes`

`POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 4611686018427238734`

`POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096`

`Maximum length of command we could actually use: 4611686018427091613`

`Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072`

It seems that the environment is much smaller than should be allowed.

Comment: @user2472441: that's very interesting. What OS/distribution are you running? Also: what do you mean by a "recursively defined array"? Is it possible to add some code to your question?

Comment: I'm running `SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP1`. Turns out the array is not the problem; I removed all the array manipulations and the problem persists. I'll add the part of the code I've isolated the bug to.

Answer (score 1):

Since you stated that when you  have a program that generates large arrays you get this bug where every command throws the error "Argument list too long". So, I presume that last command you executed is causing problem for next command. My suggestion is that don't use large argument list for any command. This could cause an overflow in the environment causing problems even for next command. Instead of large arg list, use a file having list of data and use the file redirected for input as in:

```
command < inputfile
```

Comment: Running `cp` with no arguments is hardly using a large argument list.

Comment: Caused from earlier run of some command

Comment: You'll have to explain what you're thinking of a bit more; that doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Prior subprocess executions can't change the parent process's environment + argv space usage -- any command that's going to modify environment space needs to be either the current process or a parent of same. As such, this answer reads to me as somewhat misleading.

Comment: The array is not really that large, my error begins when theres only 85 elements!
I only use these elements in a function call when I am adding or removing elements from it.
However the first command which throws the `Argument list too long` error is a `echo "something" | bc` which doesnt even depend on the array!